# Can we have the effect of CGRectIntegral on iOS 6 auto-layout generated frames?

Tags: ios, autolayout

iOS 6 auto layout is pretty handy. However, the auto-generated frames may have non-integral values. How can I force integer output for final frame positions and size using auto layout?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing constraints that wind up on half pixels in the first place, IMO.

Comment: @CodaFi It's very possible to have a constraint resulting in half pixel. For example, if you have view2 vertically centered to view1, and view1 has an odd height, then view2's center is on half pixel.

Comment: So just add one to make it even!

Comment: It does not seem like auto-layout is very useful if you have to tweak every container by a pixel here and there to make it display aligned content.  What happens when your app is auto-layout top to bottom and it still is mis-aligning content?  You are not supposed to adjust frames for ANY auto-layout content, am I supposed to go to all my users and physically add pixels to their displays?

Comment: I consider this a bug. I would expect that all coordinates and dimensions will be rounded to nearest pixel before drawing. This problem exists not only with Auto Layout, but also with manual layout. Button with `width/3` will result in subpixel rendered button – blurred.

Answer (score 10):

AutoLayout is smarter than you think.

While it's true that auto-generated frames can have fractional values, they ARE rounded to match the device's pixel ratio. On devices with Retina display (2x), fractions of 0.5 are allowed. On older devices, there don't seem to be any fractional values at all.

**This means that you'll always get a pixel-perfect layout.**

Took me quite a while to figure this out though. :)

Comment: This is not true – I have created layouts on non-retina devices where the resulting frames have fractional values, and thus cause pixel-misalignment. Something as simple as centering a view in its container.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky In my extensive tests, this was never the case. Do you have an example?

Comment: Remember, if it's a non-retina monitor attached to a retina device, you will still see antialiasing effects on the monitor.

Comment: @AndreasLey I can systematically produce fractional pixels on a non-retina device when trying to align the `NSLayoutAttributeBaseline` of a `NSTextField` to its superview's `NSLayoutAttributeCenterY`.

Comment: @Dalzhim Did you add this constraint programmatically? Does the superview have a baseline, too? Apple's documentation for Pin constraints states that *The Baseline attribute is available only when you select two or more items and all have baselines.*

Comment: Then that would be my mistake because the superview doesn't have a baseline. And yes, i added the constraint programmatically.

Comment: @AndreasLey The documentation you quoted explains constraint creation within Interface Builder. I do not think it applies to constraints built programmatically. Besides, all NSView instances have a default baselineOffset of 0 relative to the bottom. That means that a plain NSView's baseline is the same as it's bottom. Thus centering a view's baseline to its superview's CenterY should work in my opinion and I will be filing a bug report for the half-pixel problem it leads to.

Comment: @Dalzhim I suspect the constraints can't be validated at compile time and crashing the app because of an invalid constraint wouldn't be right either, so it just "goes with it". Apple seems to think that Interface Builder is the way to go and I'm sure there's a reason that baseline alignment isn't available there for a constraint between a `NSTextField` and a `NSView` (I've checked). But you're absolutely right that this shouldn't happen and filing a bug report is a good idea.

Comment: @AndreasLey The Auto Layout Programming Guide mentions that the reason invalid constraints do not make the application crash is that it is easier to debug constraints when the application is still running. Besides, there are already safeguards for various invariants such as adding a constraint to a view that isn't a common ancestor for both related views or making a syntax mistake in the visual formatting language.
I think Interface Builder limits the usage of the BaselineAttribute because it is really meant as a vertical alignment tool for text-displaying views.

Comment: I can't seem to confirm that. Do you have any reference where it states that Autolayout automatically fixes issues with sub pixel rendering?

Comment: @Andy No, I don't have any reference. This is just what I have found after experimenting with it. If you have a specific example where it doesn't work this way, I'll gladly take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer your question, unless you accept ***no***, as an answer.

I faced similar problem when using manual layout, not with Auto Layout. My solution may be useful for someone.

This code will round coordinates to *screen scale*. In other words, on standard display to integers, on Retina display to halves (0.5; 1; 1.5; …).

```
CGFloat roundToScreen(CGFloat value) {
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGFloat result = round(value * scale) / scale;
    // example value: 3.61
    // on standard display: 4
    // on Retina display: 3.5
    return result;
}
```

Here are some helper functions for `CGRect`, `CGPoint` and `CGSize`: [Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/iMartinKiss/5483361)